# How do I match a symbol in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a password validation screen and the requirement is to have at least one symbol such as the ones listed below.

How should I escape them so it works correctly under Javascript?

```
//validate symbol
if (pswd.match(/`~!@#$%^&*()_+=-\][{}\;':"<>?,/./)) {
    $('#symbol').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
} else {
    $('#symbol').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
}
```

Comment: There's only one escape character, and that's ``\``.

Comment: uh no, there's several chars in there that need to be escaped...

Comment: `$^*()+\][{}?.` all need to be escaped

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
if (pswd.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/)) {
```

It matches any text that contains at least one character that is not in the list `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: Why the set `A-B`? Don't you mean `A-Z`?

Comment: This will match even any Unicode character. Not sure whether this is good or not...

Comment: @nhahtdh you're right, but unicode characters should work under the premisse to have at least one special character in the password

Comment: @h3nr1x: I'm still a bit worry about this blacklisting approach, but since I'm not that knowledgeable about the possibility that Unicode can cause problem, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: The unicode matching makes this not work for me; thank you I'll reference this in the future

Answer (score 1):

The  slashes and right-square-bracket are the only ones that need to be escaped in a character group-as long as the hyphen is not between two characters.

```
if(/[/`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{};':"<>?,.\/\]-]/.test(pswd) ){
```

Comment: How would I escape \ and |  ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the characters that you want to match, since the original string is quite messy. Check whether this is all the characters you want:

```
"we?dn^~!@#$%^&*()_+-={dsfs}sf[]\\|:\";',./?><".match(/[`~!@#$%^&*()_+=\]\[{};':"<>?,\/.-]/g)
>> ["?", "^", "~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "+", "-", "=", "{", "}", "[", "]", ":", """, ";", "'", ",", ".", "/", "?", ">", "<"]
```

For the sake of clarity, this is the regex:

```
/[`~!@#$%^&*()_+=\]\[{};':"<>?,\/.-]/
```

**EDIT**

If you want to include `\` and `|` use this regex:

```
/[\\`~!@#$%^&*()_+=\]\[{};':"<>?,\/.|-]/
```